# Apache OpenSSL error received

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

The client is hitting a URL which is secured. Client side certificate is used for authentication. But the request does not reach the application. The certificate seems correct but the request gets stucked in between. I checked other questions which suggested to check if the URL is https and not http. I checked it and the URL on which the request is sent is HTTPS itself, but still receiving the error. Below are the apache logs :

```
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(353): ssl_scache_shmcb_store (0xcd -> subcache 13)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(645): insert happened at idx=0, data=0
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(647): finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/177
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(378): leaving ssl_scache_shmcb_store successfully
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1769): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=CD810458B34D865C3743B595016AE79FCA370D30AA839F4746446AA6A5319FDD timeout=300s (session caching)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1907): OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [info] Connection: Client IP: 62.12.14.28, Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#14f070 [mem: 136e7b] (BIO dump follows)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 17 03 03 01 90                                   .....            |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 400/400 bytes from BIO#14f070 [mem: 136e80] (BIO dump follows)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 63 2f 9f 93 d3 34 2b ba-21 dc ef de 32 b5 f4 82  c/...4+.!...2... |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0180: 57 e6 74 2c b5 b2 7e 77-aa 01 3f 49 61 39 9e 91  W.t,..~w..?Ia9.. |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server acc-b2b.kpn-wholesale.com:443)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(500): [client 62.12.14.28] Changed client verification type will force renegotiation
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1596): [client 62.12.14.28] filling buffer, max size 131072 bytes
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(353): ssl_scache_shmcb_store (0xcd -> subcache 13)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(645): insert happened at idx=0, data=0
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(647): finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/177
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(378): leaving ssl_scache_shmcb_store successfully
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1769): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=CD810458B34D865C3743B595016AE79FCA370D30AA839F4746446AA6A5319FDD timeout=300s (session caching)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1907): OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [info] Connection: Client IP: 62.12.14.28, Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#14f070 [mem: 136e7b] (BIO dump follows)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 17 03 03 01 90                                   .....            |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 400/400 bytes from BIO#14f070 [mem: 136e80] (BIO dump follows)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 63 2f 9f 93 d3 34 2b ba-21 dc ef de 32 b5 f4 82  c/...4+.!...2... |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0180: 57 e6 74 2c b5 b2 7e 77-aa 01 3f 49 61 39 9e 91  W.t,..~w..?Ia9.. |
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server acc-b2b.kpn-wholesale.com:443)
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(500): [client 62.12.14.28] Changed client verification type will force renegotiation
[Thu May 04 17:52:17 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1596): [client 62.12.14.28] filling buffer, max size 131072 bytes
[Thu May 04 17:54:39 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1940): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Thu May 04 17:54:39 2017] [info] [client 145.7.219.13] SSL handshake failed: HTTP spoken on HTTPS port; trying to send HTML error page
[Thu May 04 17:54:39 2017] [info] SSL Library Error: 336027804 error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
[Thu May 04 17:54:47 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1950): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#14f070 [mem: 136e7b]
[Thu May 04 17:54:47 2017] [info] [client 62.12.14.28] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu May 04 17:54:47 2017] [error] [client 62.12.14.28] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: could not read request body for SSL buffer
[Thu May 04 17:54:47 2017] [error] [client 62.12.14.28] could not buffer message body to allow SSL renegotiation to proceed
[Thu May 04 17:54:47 2017] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1921): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
```

Comment: What do you mean by "A certificate attached is sent for authentication"? Does that mean you use _client side_ certificates for authentication? Please add such relevant details to the question!

Comment: @arkascha : yes. edited the question now. thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)